# Trying to draw BufferedImage to file, doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I'm trying to convert a JPanel to a BufferedImage, and then save that image to a file.

DrawingPanel is a class that extends JPanel.

```
public class J extends JFrame {

    public J(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
        add(panel);

        BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(500,500);
        File file = new File("file.png");

        setVisible(true);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I get an error: `IllegalArgumentException: image == null!`
This error happens in this line:

```
ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", file);
```

What is the problem? Thanks

EDIT: The DrawingPanel class:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    }

}
```

Comment: Personally, it would probably be easier to create a new `BufferedImage` of the size of the component, or if you want to specify the size of the component, the size you need and simply use `print` passing the `Graphics` context of the `BufferedImage` to it, but that's me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: exactly.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to guess your problem since your DrawingPanel is not available to us, but it could be due to your trying to get your image before the GUI has rendered it, and in fact before it has rendered anything at all, which occurs only after calling `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageFoo extends JFrame {

   public ImageFoo() {

      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      // setSize(500, 500);
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
      add(panel);

      // BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(500, 500);
      // File file = new File("file.png");

      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

      BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(500, 500);
      File file = new File("file.png");
      try {
         ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", file);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new ImageFoo();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

   public DrawingPanel() {
      setBackground(Color.black);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      Paint paint = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.red, 20, 20, Color.blue, true);
      g2.setPaint(paint);
      g2.fillOval(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
      // setBackground(Color.BLACK); // never do in paintComponent
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

}
```

---

**Edit:** I like this attempt better

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageFoo extends JFrame {

   public ImageFoo() {

      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      // setSize(500, 500);
      final DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel();
      add(panel);

      // BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(500, 500);
      // File file = new File("file.png");

      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);

      new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            // try {
            //    Thread.sleep(300);
            // } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // }
            // BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(500, 500);

            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(DrawingPanel.PREF_W,
                  DrawingPanel.PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
            panel.paintAll(g2);
            g2.dispose();
            File file = new File("file.png");
            try {
               ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }).start();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new ImageFoo();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

   public static final int PREF_W = 500;
   public static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;

   public DrawingPanel() {
      setBackground(Color.black);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      Paint paint = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.red, 20, 20, Color.blue, true);
      g2.setPaint(paint);
      g2.fillOval(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
      // setBackground(Color.BLACK); // never do in paintComponent
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

}
```

Comment: [The doc for createImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29) seems to confirm this. *"The return value may be null if the component is not displayable."*

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. But now I have another one. The background color of the DrawingPanel is supposed to be black, but the output file has a kind of light brown color to it. I think it's the default color for JPanels. What's wrong?

Comment: @user3150201 Set the background BEFORE any painting is done, don't call `setBackground` in any paint method, actually, don't change the state of the component it's parent or any of it's children from within any paint method...

Comment: @user3150201: don't set background inside of paintComponent.

Comment: Very minor nit-pick, but shouldn't `createImage` be using the size of the component?  Never used the method myself, so I have no idea if that would make a difference (I know you've set the preferred size to meet these requirements ;))

Comment: So what should I do instead, to set the color of the JPanel? Do that from the JFrame-type class, before adding the DrawingPanel to the JFrame? Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: @user3150201 I think the problem is `createImage` doesn't do what you think it should do - *"Creates an off-screen drawable image to be used for double buffering."* - I don't think it paints anything...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: please check edit. It works better. I'm not sure if I need the Thread.sleep, and will try to remove it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I stole your code and did just about the same thing, it worked for me without using `Thread`, but `invokeLater` might be a saver choice all round.  Because we've packed the frame, the `panel` will have a size, so it should be fine doing without either, but I'll leave that up to you.  And yes, the second approach works

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure what paintAll(g2) does. I understand that paint() invokes a Component's paint() method (and I guess paintAll() is similar). But why should this method have a Graphics object as an argument? How do this work?

Comment: @user3150201: it has the Graphics context from the pre-made BufferedImage and essentially paints the component into the BufferedImage. As for what `paintAll(...)` does, you will want to read the Component API. It paints the component **and all sub components**.

Comment: @user3150201 `print` and `printAll` don't use double buffering, so it's a little faster and less resource demanding.  I've had issues with using `paint` for this type of thing when the component wasn't displayable, as it relies on native peer to perform part it's painting process (probably to do with double buffering).  `print` and `printAll` are typically use when you want to "print" a component to a printer, but this is essentially the same thing ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So basically, a Graphics object represents the graphic contents of a Component? If so, than by creating a Graphics object for the JPanel, we kind of 'copy' it's content to a new object? And if this is correct, than `panel.paintAll(g2)` pretty much 'paints' the contents of `panel` into the new Graphics object? Is some of this correct?

Comment: @user3150201: A Graphics object is like a paintbrush with which to paint with *on to one specific canvas*. Here we get a Graphics object from a BufferedImage, and so when we pass that into the components `paintAll(Graphics g)` method, we essentially "paint" the component onto the BufferedImage.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for your answer. How come your attempt with the Graphics object works, but my original attempt doesn't? (As I said, it created a image file, but didn't draw the panel inside it). What are the differences that mattered?